# Ubuntu version for laptops with limited resources

Tags: system-installation

I have a Toshiba Satellite R15-S822 tablet laptop with only 512mb of ram, 60gb hard drive, and 1.6ghz processor.  Is there a version of Ubuntu that would run on this machine.

Thanks, Bob, W.

Comment: Is that 1.6GHz CPU 64-bit capable? Or are you seeking to use a 32-bit OS? 

Comment: Seems that Bruni has done the work to determine there are no distributions supported by AskUbuntu available for your system. That said, I have found that [the Legacy (32-bit) version of Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/download/) is moderately capable on systems with 512GB of RAM and a 5400rpm HDD. Mind you, browsing the web will be dog slow if not impossible given the ridiculous resources demanded by many sites 

Comment: You can try Q4OS 32 bit (i386) with Trinity desktop environment - It claims to work with 256 MB of RAM and a 300 MHz CPU. https://q4os.org/downloads1.html  Alternatively, you can use a very old version of Ubuntu (e.g. 10.10), and use it offline (which is quite safe).

Answer (score 4):

The Toshiba Satellite R15-S822 seems to have an Intel Pentium® M Processor 725 [1.60GHz, 2MB L2 cache,
400MHz FSB]
This processor is 32 bit.
32-bit ISO images of Ubuntu are no longer being produced (as of 17.10).
So you will have to look for another linux distro.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/27584/intel-pentium-m-processor-725-2m-cache-1-60a-ghz-400-mhz-fsb/specifications.html